# Reading a Text File One Line at a Time in Windows 8.1 Application

Tags: c#, streamreader, windows-8.1-universal

I added this code to the `OnNavigatedTo` function:

```
int counter = 0;   
string line;
string path = "Streams\\Usernames.txt";

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file =
   new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Lbx_Usernames.Items.Add(line);
    counter++;
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Steam'

Comment: at which line...to be exact?

Comment: System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);

Comment: the code won't compile. what is the line `new System.IO.StreamReader()`? I guess you pasted it by mistake?

Comment: I want to read the text file one line at a time in my Windows 8.1 (universal) application, got a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

First off, there are many differences in the API sets that are used in a desktop application and a Windows 8.1 (Universal) application.

This

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(string path);
```

is only available in **desktop applications** (Console, WinForm/WPF).

In **Windows Store apps**, you can use [FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(IStorageFile)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701475.aspx) to read all text from a file, which accepts a [StorageFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) as an argument, and returns a list of lines and you can iterate through each line.

This [sample](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/reading-and-writing-file-in-windows-8-apps-using-C-Sharp/) can get you started.